# Is there a way to use exec inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exec

The function:

```
def thefunction():
  exec("x = 'text'")
  return x
print(thefunction())
```

and it doesnt work...
this is for python 3

Comment: Have you read the [`exec` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)?

Answer (score 2):

Give it a dict as a storage for variables.

```
def thefunction():
  vars = {}
  exec("x = 'text'", vars)
  return vars['x']

print(thefunction())
```

In any case, read the documentation and warnings about `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass in your locals or it will only be local to that ...

```
def thefunction():
   my_locals = locals()
   exec("x = 'text'",globals(),my_locals)
   return my_locals['x']

print(thefunction())
```

you can make it a little safer by sending in an isolated environment... but the bottom line is that its not safe to `exec` untrusted input

Comment: It gives me `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, in Python 3.10.8. It is valid to use `globals()` as the third argument, which writes the result to the global variable, then retrieves `x` from the global variable and returns it.

Comment: I just double checked ... it works perfectly in my interpretter ... (I did have globals and locals swapped earlier .... but that should not have resulted in a nameerror)

Comment: Did you delete `x` from the global variable and retest it? The local variable of the function is now implemented using an array. The [document of `exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) never guarantees that it can work properly in the function...

Comment: @JoranBeasley you sure you are using Python 3?

Comment: @MechanicPig that's not true. It just won't modify the function's local namespace.  But you can pass in your own namespace and it should work

Comment: edited you are correct ... once i restarted i got the error ... fixed now i think  .... not sure why you have to do that but i saw it did not work :) (TIL)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean, it doesn't work like it does in top-level statements (such as accessing the assigned variable directly by name instead of using a dictionary), my wording may be a bit problematic.